# Webpack Compilation failed while generating dist bundle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I had an angularjs application built with bower and gulp that I decided to migrate to webpack. I moved all my code to ES6 and I got it working for a dev webpack config with no issues at all: source maps included, not uglifying, not minifying...

Now I want to generate a new version of that config where I include the typical production tasks. Overall, I want to be able to generate two bundles: one for vendor and for my the app code.

```
const pkg = require('../package.json');
// ...
new ExtractTextPlugin('index-[contenthash].css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({name: 'vendor'}),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      }
    })
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.dist),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
  },
  entry: {
    app: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies)
  }
```

When I do that change for the new vendor entry file and the common chunck plugin then compilation fails with the following error:

```
ERROR in multi angular angular-aria angular-bootstrap... // all package.json depedencies
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular-consent' in 'path/to/my/project'
```

This error gets logged several times and then a different one:

```
ERROR in ./~/swagger-ui/dist/swagger-ui.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'b'
ERROR in ./~/modernizr/lib/options.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'
// more of the same pattern
```

What am I missing? Do I have a dependency breaking the vendor bundle?

**Versions**:
angular: 1.5.8, webpack: 2.7.0.
**OS**: windows 10 and OSX El Capitan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with certain packages I was declaring in my dependencies package.json: angular-consent and font-awesome. Reason why they don't need to be included is well covered here [Error including font-awesome with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116920/error-including-font-awesome-with-webpack).

In my case:

```
const excludeDeps= ['angular-consent', 'font-awesome'];

  entry: {
    app: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`,
    vendor: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies).filter(name => (excludeDeps.indexOf(name) === -1))
  }
```